# Encode AV1 in mpegts container

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert h264 video to av1 and save it in mpegts container.

I managed to encode av1 and use mp4 or mkv containers but it doesn't work with mpegts.
All I can find is that av1 mpegts support is "in planning" - any idea regarding to its roadmap?

Can av1 can be used in mpegts container?
Can ffmpeg encode av1 into mpegts container?

Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are 3 questions here, and the answer to the 2 latter ones is obviously “not at the moment” according to the rest of your text.

Comment: thanks for response,

"not at the moment" is the "simple" answer :)

I'm trying to understand when will it be available, and find any other information regarding ffmpeg with av1 and mpegts support...

Comment: Only your first question is about "when", and I don't know. Then I gave the simple answer to the 2 other ones.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 Dec AV1 in a TS container is still work in progress which is why it's hard to find programs which support that specification.

The draft specifications are available here: https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-mpeg2-ts/

Once the specification is standardized and adopted you should see more programs supporting AV1 in TS